# OS X: Always have an app open at specific location in the Dock, without permanently keeping it in the Dock?

Tags: macos, dock

Let's say, I sometimes want to use *Application XYZ*, but I **don't** want to set its Dock Option to ***Keep in Dock*** so its icon is visible at all time.

When I want to use the application, I open it with Spotlight. It will open and place itself to the right end of the applications in the Dock.

I would prefer it to lie closer to the middle.

Is there a way to place it at a specific location permanently, *without* having to always keep it there, regardless of whether it's active or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Apps that are not kept in dock when opened will be positioned at the end of the dock.